# Working with an SC7A20 accelerometer on an STM32 microcontroller using STM32CubeIDE and code adaptation

Tags: stm32

How to interface SC7A20 accelerometer with STM32 using the Stm32 cube ide?

I'm trying to interface the SC7A20 accelerometer with an STM32 microcontroller using the Stm32 cubeIDE and a JTAG programmer. I have the following code snippet from the STM32Cube IDE, and I want to adapt it to work with the Stm32 cubeIDE.

```
#define SC7A20_I2C_ADDRESS 0x1C
#define SC7A20_CTRL_REG1 0x20
#define SC7A20_OUT_X_H_REG 0x28
#define SC7A20_OUT_X_L_REG 0x29
#define SC7A20_OUT_Y_H_REG 0x2A
#define SC7A20_OUT_Y_L_REG 0x2B
#define SC7A20_OUT_Z_H_REG 0x2C
#define SC7A20_OUT_Z_L_REG 0x2D 
#define WHO_AM_I 0x00
#define POWER_MODE 0x01
#define RANGE 0x02
#define DATA_RATE 0x03

void SC7A20_Init(void) {
uint8_t sendData;
uint8_t check_val;
// Read the WHO_AM_I register to check if the device is present.
HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, SC7A20_ADDRESS, WHO_AM_I, 1, &check_val, 1, 1000);

// If the device is present, initialize it.
if (check_val == 0x01) {
    // Set the power mode to standby.
    sendData = 0x00;
    HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, SC7A20_ADDRESS, POWER_MODE, 1, &sendData, 1, 1000);

    // Set the measurement range to 16-bit.
    sendData = 0x00;
    HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, SC7A20_ADDRESS, RANGE, 1, &sendData, 1, 1000);

    // Set the data rate to 100Hz.
    sendData = 0x00;
    HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, SC7A20_ADDRESS, DATA_RATE, 1, &sendData, 1, 1000);
}

int main() {
SC7A20_Init();
while (1) {
    uint8_t x_axis_h, x_axis_l, y_axis_h, y_axis_l, z_axis_h, z_axis_l;
    HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, SC7A20_I2C_ADDRESS, SC7A20_OUT_X_H_REG, 1, &x_axis_h, 1, 100);
    HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, SC7A20_I2C_ADDRESS, SC7A20_OUT_X_L_REG, 1, &x_axis_l, 1, 100);
    HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, SC7A20_I2C_ADDRESS, SC7A20_OUT_Y_H_REG, 1, &y_axis_h, 1, 100);
    HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, SC7A20_I2C_ADDRESS, SC7A20_OUT_Y_L_REG, 1, &y_axis_l, 1, 100);
    HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, SC7A20_I2C_ADDRESS, SC7A20_OUT_Z_H_REG, 1, &z_axis_h, 1, 100);
    HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, SC7A20_I2C_ADDRESS, SC7A20_OUT_Z_L_REG, 1, &z_axis_l, 1, 100);

    double x_axis, y_axis, z_axis;

    // Calculate the acceleration values
    x_axis = (x_axis_h << 4) | x_axis_l;
    y_axis = (y_axis_h << 4) | y_axis_l;
    z_axis = (z_axis_h << 4) | z_axis_l;
}
```

}

Comment: You made a mistake in your question. What exactly do you want? " I have the following code snippet from the **STM32Cube IDE**, and I want to adapt it to work with the **Stm32 cubeIDE**". Also, I see no I2C hardware initialization at all.

Comment: i want to calcuate acclerometer acceleration, i initilze i2c as I2C1_SCL(pb6)
I2C1_SDA(pb7)

Comment: What does (or does not) work about your code? Have you tried stepping through it with a debugger? Do you have a logic analyser or oscilloscope you can use to observe the I2C bus? You question is very, very vague.

Comment: "i initilze i2c as I2C1_SCL(pb6) I2C1_SDA(pb7)", how did you initialise the i2c1? your `main()` obviously never have any code to setup the i2c port by calling something like `hal_i2c_init();` (nor setting up system clock, etc.) . Use the STM32CubeIDE to config and generate the basic setup code, and copy and paste into your code.

Comment: I initilaze all the peripheral and their code as well, i just want you to correct what is the mistake in the above code